# Getting high current pulses from a low current source?

Tags: power, capacitor, current

I need to switch on/off a coil draining a high current (close to 1A) during intermittent small intervals (500 ms). Unfortunately, my source is only capable of 100mA in small bursts (say 100 ms).

So, I thought of using a big tank capacitor which I would first charge (either with one pulse, or several pulses). Then, once charged, it could be used to supply the high current that my coil needs.  Does this idea make sense? If not, what could I do there?

Comment: How long does the coil need the 1A current for?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Simple but very effective]

WARNING - This circuit can create RF interference to unusually high frequencies.
Shield everything.